# JavaScript IntersectionObserver Incorrect Behaviour with DOM Layout changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intersection-observer, golden-layout

**Expected Behaviour:**  `IntersectionObserver` must correctly report the observed component's visibility in the viewport.
**Current Behaviour:** `IntersectionObserver` incorrectly reports component as invisible despite being in the viewport when another component is dragged and dropped to change the DOM layout.

[image]

My `useOnScreen` hook -

```
// intersection observer is buggy with golden layout
// move C component and keep all in view, but B component will be marked not on screen
function useOnScreen(label, ref) {
  const [isOnScreen, setIsOnScreen] = useState(false);
  const observerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    observerRef.current = new IntersectionObserver(
      ([entry]) => {
        setIsOnScreen(entry.isIntersecting);
      },
      { root: document.body }
    );
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    observerRef.current.observe(ref.current);

    return () => {
      observerRef.current.disconnect();
    };
  }, [ref]);

  return isOnScreen;
}
```

How I use this hook in my React component -

```
const Text = ({ label }) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const onScreen = useOnScreen(label, ref);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (onScreen) {
      console.log("onscreen", label);
      return () => {
        console.log("not on screen", label);
      };
    }
  }, [onScreen, label]);

  return <h1 ref={ref}>{label}</h1>;
};
```

Demo Video of the bug: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W54-D3BT7FNqZNS4EzBDYdJFqdHD-iCx/view?usp=sharing

Code Setup for the bug: https://codesandbox.io/s/golden-layout-react-intersection-observer-zhnq3c?file=/src/App.js:289-615

---

**My Approach**

- I noticed that `rootBounds.width` and `rootBounds.height` are `0` in the `IntersectionObserverEntry` for component `B` when DOM layout is changed on drag/drop of component `C`.
- Hence, it feels component `B` is not in view because the viewport is of `0` size
- I even tried with passing `options.root = document.body` while creating the `IntersectionObserver` in its constructor but still same issue.
- If I chose to ignore the callback when `rootBounds` is of `0` size, I will then miss legit cases where a component `B` is not in viewport but the hook will still keep it as visible.
- The next solution I think is to hook into `GoldenLayout` events to track which tabs are active and which are not and pass that prop to my Components somehow.
- Is there a better solution here?

Comment: Your `IntersectionObserver` callback only handles cases where exactly 1 `IntersectionObserverEntry` object is supplied - it doesn't handle cases where the callback has multiple entries passed into it. Could that be part of the problem?

Comment: I have created multiple `IntersectionObserver`  - one for each component. So I don't think that's the issue, you can have a look at the code via `codesandbox link` I shared above in the problem description. 
The issue is `entry.rootBounds` has `width: 0` and `height: 0` which means it feels the viewport does not exist.

Comment: I ran it on the link you gave and I set a breakpoint on the line where you're calling `setIsOnScreen` and I see **two** entries in the array, and the second entry has `isIntersecting: true` but the first entry is `false` which is where the "not on screen" message comes from - so that's definitely part of, if not _the_, problem.

Comment: Screenshot proof right here: https://imgur.com/a/WxO7Kxx

Comment: Thanks, that's quite weird, why would the callback have two entries, if there is a single observer?

Comment: Read the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/observe - or better yet, the specification: https://w3c.github.io/IntersectionObserver/#callbackdef-intersectionobservercallback

Comment: I see, but still its not clear why the first entry has rootBounds as `0` for the viewport.

Comment: The zero-values represent an _edge-adjacent intersection_ (i.e. the two elements are "touching" each other and not strictly overlapping), that's described in section 2.3